# Can we set minimum samples per leaf in XGBoost (like in other GBM algos)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm curious why [xgBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) doesn't support the `min_samples_leaf` parameter like the classic [GB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) classifier in sklearn? And if I do want to control the min. number of samples on a single leaf, is there any workaround in xgboost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `min_child_weight`. According to the documentation, this parameter:

> minimum sum of instance weight (hessian) needed in a child.

For regression problems with MSE loss, the sum of instance weight will result in the minimum samples per leaf node because the second derivative of MSE loss equals one.

For classification problems, it will result in a different metric that characterizes the purity of the samples in a leaf node (e.g., for binary classification, if a proportion of samples of one class heavily dominate the other classes in a leaf — there is no need to split it further).

I don't know about a specific reason for not having `min_samples_leaf` parameter. I guess its interference with `min_child_weight` will bring some design challenges and confusion to the users.

Comment: This is frustrating because obviously `min_samples_leaf` is far more intuitive than `min_child_weight`!

Answer (score 1):

xgboost has `min_child_weight`, but outside of the ordinary regression task that is indeed different from minimum samples.  I couldn't say *why* the additional parameter isn't included.  Note though that in binary classification, the logloss hessian is `p(1-p)` and is between 0 and 1/4, with values near zero for the very confident predictions; so in effect setting `min_child_weight` is requiring many currently-uncertain rows in each leaf, which may be close enough to (or better than!) setting a minimum number of rows.